# Extracting equations from Piecewise expressions

Tags: syntax, probability-or-statistics, expression-manipulation

Say I have a PDF:

```
PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65], x]
```

Calculating it, Mathematica gives me an expression that looks like this:

[image]

I want to extract the equation itself so I can use it in other calculations.  On a one off basis, I can do that with `Part[]`:

```
PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65], x][[1, 1, 1]]
```

which gives me the following:

[image]

That's fine, but I need something more universal.  For instance, for a different PDF that looks like this:

[image]

I could get what I need with:

```
%[[1, 2, 1]]
```

You see my dilemma.  How do I extract the business part of such expressions in a more universal way so I can use them in other calculations and functions that may need to deal with a variety of such expressions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way to separate your equation into different subparts. It uses `Reap` and `Sow` to tag parts of the expression as either `"equation"` or `"conditions"` or `"constants"`.

```
f = Which[FreeQ[#, x], Sow[#, "constants"],
        MemberQ[{Equal, Unequal, Greater, GreaterEqual, Less, LessEqual, And, Or}, Head[#]], 
        Sow[#, "conditions"],True, Sow[#, "equation"]] &;

Last@Reap[Scan[f, List @@ PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65], x] // Flatten], 
    {"equation", "conditions", "constants"}] ~Flatten~ 1

(* Out[1]= {{(0.613757 E^(-1.18343 (-1.75 + Log[x])^2))/x}, {x > 0}, {0}} *)
```

So now you have your equations in the first sublist, conditions in the second and constants in the third. If you need only the first, you need to `Reap` only that. This should work with your second example too.

Note that you'll have to be careful to ensure that `x` above does not have any value — using [formal symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html) is better.

Comment: Many thanks.  Your suggestion works nicely in my application and you grasped the intent of my question relative to what I needed to do exactly.  This might not work in every situation, but in mine where I need to assess pdfs it show work perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

Since you get the result in terms of `Piecewise`, you can use things like `Refine` or `Simplify`, particularly when you want to get a result given some additional condition on your variables. In particular,

```
Refine[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65], x], x > 0]

(* ==>  (0.613757 E^(-1.18343 (-1.75+Log[x])^2))/x  *)
```

Comment: @Leonid_Shifrin I'm confused.  To get what I want with Refine, it seems I would need to know the condition(s) before hand.  Identifying the conditions programmatically seems much like the same problem with which I started.

Comment: @Jagra, if you don't know the condition beforehand, explain in words how would you choose what expression you want to extract for the general case (in which you might have more than a single "big formula"

Comment: @Jagra You have to somehow identify the piece in your function you want to extract. You did this by indicating position of it inside `Piecewise`, but were apparently unsatisfied because that was fragile. I agree. But to have  it *not* fragile, the only option I see is to use conditions for this, at least if you want to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 7):

"How do I extract the business part of such expressions in a more universal way?"

Well, do you always know what the "business part" of your expression is?

For instance,

```
pw = Series[Piecewise[{{Cos[x], x <= 0}}, E^x], {x, a, 2}]
```

gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What's the business part there?

I believe you're thinking of the most complex piece in the `Piecewise` expression. If that's the case you could use a function like `LeafCount` to provide a measure of complexity.

```
SortBy[pw[[1, All, 1]], LeafCount][[-1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
pw = Piecewise[{{x^2 + x, x > 0}, {0, x == 0}, {1, x < 0}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SortBy[pw[[1, All, 1]], LeafCount][[-1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: While not as relevant as the solution R.M. supplied for my specific application, I very much appreciate your input on this.  I learned something which should prove very useful in the future.  Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple answer here:

```
pdf = PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1.75, 0.65], x];
pdf[[1, 1, 1]]

(* (0.613757 E^(-1.18343 (-1.75 + Log[x])^2))/x *)
```

To see that you need `{1,1,1}`, and not another term use the `TreeForm` expression:

```
TreeForm[pdf]
```