# What is the difference between a few simplification techniques?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I am trying to understand the difference between `Refine`, `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`, and when it's more appropriate to use a particular one. The help files on this are not entirely clear. For example, under the help for `Refine` it says

> Use `Simplify` for more simplification rules:
>
> ```
> Refine[Sqrt[x^2 + 2 x y + y^2], x + y >= 0]
> (* Sqrt[x^2 + 2 x y + y^2] *)
>
> Simplify[Sqrt[x^2 + 2 x y + y^2], x + y >= 0]
> (* x + y *)
> ```

From this, I can't imagine why anyone would ever use `Refine`, if `Simplify` will get it simpler. Yet, it keeps turning up in answers on this site (e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3371/9), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3957/9), or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1064/9)), where `Simplify` would also work.

Then, regarding `Simplify` vs `FullSimplify`, the help file states:

> Use `FullSimplify` to simplify expressions involving special functions:

Is there a guideline for which sorts of functions are considered "special functions"?

I realize that (based on the "More Information" section and personal experience) `FullSimplify` may take longer, but under what circumstances? Is a good general approach to try `Simplify` first, and then only if one is unhappy with the results, then try `FullSimplify`?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Special-Functions-Encyclopedia-Mathematics-Applications/dp/0521789885 :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The primary difference between `Refine` and the two `*Simplify` functions is that `Refine` only *evaluates* the expression according to the assumptions given. It might so happen to be the simplest form when evaluated, but it does not check to see if it is indeed the simplest possible form. You should use `Refine` when your goal is not to simplify the expression but to just see how the assumptions transform it (e.g., square root of a positive quantity).

`Simplify`, on the other hand, performs basic algebraic simplifications and transformations to arrive at the "simplest" result. `Refine` is one among them, and is also mentioned in its doc page. Here, "simplest" might not necessarily fit your definition of simple. It is what appears simple to Mathematica, and that is defined by [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LeafCount.html). Here's an example showing the difference between the two:

```
Refine[(x - 1)/Sqrt[x^2] + 1/x, x > 0]
(* Out= 1/x + (-1 + x)/x *)

Simplify[(x - 1)/Sqrt[x^2] + 1/x, x > 0]
(* Out= 1 *)
```

`FullSimplify` behaves the same as `Simplify`, except that it also does manipulations and simplifications when it involves special functions. It is indeed slower, as a result, because it has to try all the available rules. The list of special functions is found in [`guide/SpecialFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SpecialFunctions.html) and it's not a non-standard usage of the term and you can also read about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions). So in all cases not involving special functions, you should use `Simplify`. You can certainly give `FullSimplify` a try if you're not satisfied with `Simplify`'s result, but it helps to not start with it if you don't need it.

Here's an example showing the difference between `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`:

```
Simplify[BesselJ[n, x] + I BesselY[n, x]]
(* BesselJ[n, x] + I BesselY[n, x] *)

FullSimplify[BesselJ[n, x] + I BesselY[n, x]]
(* HankelH1[n, x] *)
```

---

#### A few more notes on `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`:

As you have noted, `FullSimplify` is slow — sometimes it can take hours on end to arrive at the answer. The default for `TimeConstrained`, which is an option, is `Infinity`, which means that `FullSimplify` will take its sweet time to expand/transform until it is satisfied. However, it could very well be the case that a bulk of the time is spent trying out various transformations (which might eventually be futile) and the actual simplification step is quick. It helps to try out with a shorter time, and the [documentation has a good example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0i1l727rm-mz5gp) that shows this. This holds for `Simplify` too.

Note that setting the option `TimeConstrained -> t` does **not** mean that you'll get your answer in under `t` seconds. Rather, it means that Mathematica is allowed to spend at most `t` seconds for a single transformation/simplification step.

Similarly, you can exclude certain functions from being simplified using `ExcludedForms` or include other custom transformations using `TransformationFunctions`. You can even change the default measure of "simplicity" using `ComplexityFunction`, and [here is an answer that uses this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4293/5). However, these options are not available in `Refine`.

These are actually well documented in the documentation for both functions, but is not widely known and can often be the key to getting the result quickly or in the form you want.

Comment: Interesting. They say `FullSimplify` is often slow, and I see that as a reason not to go there first. But, is `Simplify` measurably faster than `Refine`?

Comment: @Eli: "They say `FullSimplify[]` is often slow..." - sure, it has to consider way more transformation rules than `Simplify[]`; there are a lot more special functions than elementary functions...

Comment: As an example: `Simplify[Gamma[x] Gamma[1 - x]]` is unproductive, while `FullSimplify[Gamma[x] Gamma[1 - x]]` does produce something "simpler". On the other hand, to get the full benefit of `FullSimplify[]`, you will sometimes have to do a preliminary application of `FunctionExpand[]`.

Comment: I understand the difference/benefits of `FullSimplify` vs `Simplify` and I've seen the various examples in the help file. What about `Refine`? Why ever use it?

Comment: @EliLansey See my edits

Comment: I find your example of `Refine` not very insightful as it doesn't do anything at all. Can't you provide an example of a case where I would want to use it?

Comment: @Sjoerd Sure, try `Refine[(x - 1)/Sqrt[x^2] + 1/x, x > 0]`. It correctly replaces `√x^2` with `x`, but doesn't do anything more, whereas `Simplify` rightly gives you 1.

Comment: @R.M: very good answer, but since the question about potential "slowness" of `FullSimplify` has come up you probably might want to add a note about the presettings of the `TimeConstraint` options of the three functions. I think this is an important detail one should be aware of, especially since in combination with caching the result of consecutive runs might differ. It's probably also worth noting that one can control the rules to try (`TransformationFunctions`) and measure of simplicity (`CompexityFunction`).

Comment: @R.M I suggest you add that example to the main text.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Good point. I'll surely do that in the morning

Comment: A bit unrelated: how did you create the following link for a subsection of the online documentation: http://wolfram.com/xid/0i1l727rm-mz5gp ? Can't figure out how to do it! :)

Comment: @Stan I described it here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/478/5 Please also see the comment re: browsers. It's now been almost 5 years, so I don't know if they still hold true or if things have improved since then.

Answer (score 20):

**`Refine` vs `Simplify`**

Mathematica is a term rewriting system, whenever we enter an expression, then it is evaluated by term rewriting using (built-in or user-defined) rewrite rules (see e.g. [Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html)) , so by default it "simplifies" some expressions, e.g. :

```
a + b - a
```

> ```
> b
> ```

So this makes an impression, that `Refine` performs some simplifications, although documentation states that it yields the form of an expression  which would be obtained if symbols in it were replaced by explicit numerical expressions satisfying the assumptions (defualt if not specified).

However, sometimes algorithms behind `Simplify` appear not easily adjusting to do simple tasks unlike  `Refine`, although they contain transformations done by `Refine`.  A direct example :

```
{Refine, Simplify, FullSimplify} @@ {-Re[x + y], (x | y) \[Element] Reals} // Through
```

> ```
> {-x - y, -Re[x + y], -Re[x + y]}
> ```

We can get `-(x+y)` with `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` as well if we choose an appropriate `ComplexityFunction` (not accessible with `Refine`), you may look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4135/why-doesnt-fullsimplify-drop-the-re-function-from-an-expression-known-to-be-rea/4190#4190). Simplification techniques  offered by `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` include options like `Trig`, `TransformationFunctions`,`ExcludedForms` etc.  unlike for `Refine`, where we can specify only assumptions or `TimeConstraint`.

**`Simplify` vs `FullSimplify`**

*Expressions involving special functions*

`FullSimplify` allows simplifications involving special functions unlike `Simplify`.  There is no general definition of special functions, but basic ones are solutions of second order linear ordinary differential equations like e.g. hypergeometric functions, Bessel functions, Gegenbauer polynomials etc. on the other hand i.e. Riemann zeta function $\zeta\;$, one of the most amazing special functions is not a solution of any differential equation, however  there is e.g. a functional equation relating it to Euler $\Gamma\;$ function :
 $$ \zeta(z) = 2^z\pi^{z-1}\ \sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\ \Gamma(1-z)\ \zeta(1-z)$$
which helps to find easily trivial zeros of $\zeta$.

```
A = Through /@ {Simplify, FullSimplify} /@ {2^z Pi^(z - 1) Sin[Pi z/2] Gamma[1 - z] Zeta[1 - z], 
                                            Gamma[1 - x] Gamma[x] Sin[Pi x]};
Grid[ Array[ InputField[ Dynamic[ A[[#1, #2]]], FieldSize -> 20] &, {2, 2}]]
```

[image]

*Elementary expressions*

`Simplify` is clearly more limited than `FullSimplify` and the differences are distingushible *not only for special functions*. See for example [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4575/surprises-simplifying-simple-polynomials) for an apparent difference of behaviors for simple polynomials. 
Here is another difference for quite elementary expressions  :

```
Through @ { Simplify, FullSimplify } @ 
          (Sqrt[ a^2 - 2 a b c + b^2 c^2] /. {a -> 8, b -> Sqrt[2], c -> 3})
```

> ```
> { Sqrt[ 82 - 48 Sqrt[2]], 8 - 3 Sqrt[2]}
> ```

Clearly, if we assume e.g. `b -> Sqrt[2]`, then `Simplify` cannot tackle such a simple expression, 
although it can do it on a more general symbolic level if an appropriate assumption is given :

```
{Simplify, FullSimplify} @@ {Sqrt[a^2 - 2 a b c + b^2 c^2], a - b c > 0} // Through
```

> ```
> {a - b c, a - b c}
> ```

and we see that `Refine` does not simplify anything here.

Another  slightly more involved example, where `Simplify` works with assumptions only on the symbolic level :

```
Column @ 
  Through @ 
    ({Refine, Simplify, FullSimplify} @@ 
      {a + b + c - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2 b c + 2 Sqrt[a^2 b^2 + a^2 c^2 + 2 (a^2) b c]],
       a > 0 && b + c > 0})
```

[image]

but not for numeric values :

```
Column @ Through @ {Refine, Simplify, FullSimplify} @
(Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[3] + 3 Sqrt[5] - Sqrt[ 12 Sqrt[15] + 2 Sqrt[24 Sqrt[15] + 114] + 59])
```

[image]
`Refine` dosen't do anything here, i.e. it works here just like `Identity`, `Simplify` here only groups terms (`24 Sqrt[15] + 114 -> 6( 19 + 4 Sqrt[15]`), while `FullSimplify` does the full simplification.

Using `Simplify` is of course advantageous (because of time needed to perform a task) when we want to deal with large expressions and apply some simple algebraic transformations, e.g. for tensors in general relativity.

Comment: +1 For the example where `Refine` gives a simpler expression than `*Simplify~.

Comment: "There is no general definition of special functions..." - the working definition I'm accustomed to is that it's "special" if it's not an elementary function (algebraics, exponentials, logarithms, trigonometric/hyperbolic functions and their inverses, combinations and compositions thereof.)

Comment: "...no general definition...", you mentioned the working definition, there is also "...solutions of second order linear ordinary differential equations of mathematical physics". Those both are quite different so the statement "there is no general definition of special functions..." is perfectly correct.