# Simplifying expressions with square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I would like *Mathematica* to simplify this expression:

$4 \left(16 \sqrt{\left(-1+2 c^2\right)^2}-32 c^2 \sqrt{\left(-1+2 c^2\right)^2}+\sqrt{\left(1-8 c^2+8 c^4\right)^2}\right)^2$

```
expression = 4*( 16*Sqrt[(-1 + 2*c^2)^2] - 32*c^2*Sqrt[(-1 + 2*c^2)^2] 
                 + Sqrt[(1 - 8*c^2 + 8*c^4)^2])^2;
```

I have tried

```
PowerExpand[expression]

FullSimplify[expression]
```

but they did not simplify `expression`.

Comment: are you assuming that c is Real and did you tell Mathematica that?

Answer (score 7):

The simplification that I think you are looking for only works if you tell *Mathematica* to assume `c` is real. Try

```
Simplify[4*(16*Sqrt[(-1 + 2*c^2)^2] - 
     32*c^2*Sqrt[(-1 + 2*c^2)^2] + 
     Sqrt[(1 - 8*c^2 + 8*c^4)^2])^2, 
  c ∈ Reals]
```

> 4 ((16 - 32 c^2) Abs[1 - 2 c^2] + Abs[1 - 8 c^2 + 8 c^4])^2

Answer (score 7):

We should exploit the second argument in `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` being an assumption on possible variables or symbols in a given axpression. For more complete discussion of simplification methods see the answers to this question [What is the difference between a few simplification techniques?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/what-is-the-difference-between-a-few-simplification-techniques).

One should have consider a few cases since we could use various assumptions. Let's start with plotting graphs of polynomial functions apprearing in the expression. We'd like to distinguish cases where  `1 - 8 c^2 + 8 c^4` and `1 - 2 c^2` are non-negative.

```
Plot[{ 1 - 8 c^2 + 8 c^4, 1 - 2 c^2}, {c, -4/3, 4/3}, 
       PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

There are two independent terms which can be simplified in different ways with respect to assumptions given, e.g.

```
Simplify[ Sqrt[(-1 + 2 c^2)^2], #]& /@ {-(1/Sqrt[2]) < c < 1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2] < c} //  
Column
```

> ```
>  1 - 2 c^2
> -1 + 2 c^2
> ```

We shouldn't impose accidental assumptions since expressions couldn't be simplified to the simplest form (appropriate assumptions for the first term, in general will not be adequate for the other one), e.g.

```
Simplify[ expression, #] & /@ {-(1/Sqrt[2]) < c < 1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2] < c} // Column
```

> ```
> 4 ( 16 (1 - 2 c^2)^2 + Abs[1 - 8 c^2 + 8 c^4])^2
> 4 (-16 (1 - 2 c^2)^2 + Abs[1 - 8 c^2 + 8 c^4])^2
> ```

Here `Sqrt[(1 - 8 c^2 + 8 c^4)^2]` could be simplified only to `Abs[1 - 8 c^2 + 8 c^4]` since it is the most general (and the simplest) form satisfying imposed assumptions.

Now, in order to complete simplification we need to deal with `Reduce` for writing down different assumptions:

```
Grid[(cs = Table[ Reduce[ g[1 - 8 c^2 + 8 c^4, 0] && h[1 - 2 c^2, 0], c], 
                  {g, {GreaterEqual, Less}}, {h, {GreaterEqual, Less}}]), 
      Frame -> All] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

and the simplifications are respectively:

```
Grid[ Map[ Simplify[ 4(16Sqrt[(-1 + 2c^2)^2] - 32c^2 Sqrt[(-1 + 2 c^2)^2] + 
                     Sqrt[(1 - 8c^2 + 8c^4)^2])^2, #] &, cs, {2}], 
      Frame -> All] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

In general for more involved expressions one should deal with `FullSimplify`, nevertheless we get in our case the same expressions with `Simplify`.

Comment: Very useful stuff.  I need you in my corner if I ever return to Project Euler problems. :-)