# How to simplify to form without imaginary unit

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have an integral that I compute with Mathematica and as a result I get a seemingly complex expression (i.e. the expression contains the imaginary unit, $i$, at some places). However, if I try to numerically compute the values of this expression at some values of my variables, I notice that in fact the value of the result is always real (for real values of variables); the imaginary parts cancel out in a right way to make the result real. This is also evident from the fact that the expression is a solution to a physical problem that is supposed to give a real solution.

How do I make Mathematica simplify the expression so that it doesn't contain any imaginary units anymore?

Edit:

The expression I'm trying to simplify is:

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{-i x+y+1}}}{x+i (y-1)}+\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{i x+y+1}}}{x-i (y-1)}$$

In Mathematica form:

```
Sqrt[1 - 2/(1 - I x + y)]/(x + I (-1 + y)) + Sqrt[1 - 2/(1 + I x + y)]/(x - I (-1 + y))
```

Comment: Look at [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexExpand.html).  Otherwise please provide a sample problem.

Comment: I provided the expression I'm trying to simplify.

Comment: You can't simplify your expression to another one explicitly real without appropriate assumptions. Try e.g. `With[{x = -1, y = -1}, 
 FullSimplify[
  Sqrt[(1 - 2/(-I x + y + 1))/(x + I (y - 1))] + Sqrt[(
   1 - 2/(I x + y + 1))/(x - I (y - 1))]]]` which yields `2 I`. This post shows how one could approach similar problems [Simplifying expressions with square roots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29310/simplifying-expressions-with-square-roots/29357#29357).

Comment: @Artes -- you've got the square root in the wrong place. The OPs function is `f[x_, y_] := 
 Sqrt[(1 - 2/(-I x + y + 1))]/(x + I (y - 1)) + 
  Sqrt[(1 - 2/(I x + y + 1))]/(x - I (y - 1))` which is real-valued (at least at -1,-1).

Comment: The expression reduces to:
$$
\sqrt{2} \, \text{sign}(x) 
\frac{ 
    \sqrt{
       \left(x^2+(y-1)^2\right) 
       \left(
          1 + x^2 - y^2
          + \sqrt{
             2 \left( x^2-1 \right) y^2 
             + \left( x^2+1 \right)^2
             + y^4
          }
        \right)
    }
}{
    \left( x^2+(y-1)^2 \right)
    \sqrt{x^2+y^2+2 y+1}
}
$$
but I cannot find an easy way to get *Mathematica* to produce it.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have tried using Assumptions in Fullsimplify, but it doesn't help. Thanks for solution, Hbar, I will check this myself and use it. However, I have also another (much longer) expression that I would also like to get in an explicitly real form so still I would like to see how to produce this with Mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with simplifying things with square roots is remaining in the branch while assuming that $\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ a b}$.  Getting this right usually requires analyzing the possible values of $a$ and $b$.  For your expression, `ComplexExpand` gives just a few simple `Arg`s to deal with, making it possible to finish the problem with a substitution.

```
f = Sqrt[1 - 2/(1 - I x + y)]/(x + I (-1 + y)) + 
   Sqrt[1 - 2/(1 + I x + y)]/(x - I (-1 + y));
f1 = ComplexExpand[f];
modify[u_] := ArcTan@FullSimplify[
    ComplexExpand@Im[u]/ComplexExpand@Re[u]
    ];
f2 = f1 /. Arg[x_] :> modify[x];
result = FullSimplify[FunctionExpand@Simplify[f2]]
```

Not very elegant, but will work with simple roots.

Comment: It seems to work... almost. When I plot the expression I get as a result it looks like it differs from the original expression for arguments $|y|,|x|<1$. I don't really understand what this does, though. I guess my Mathematica knowledge is lacking. What does @ and :> do?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out your code. I still have to figure out how to repair the wrong result for certain arguments. It probably has something to do with choosing the wrong branch of arctan or something.