# How to "ReplaceAll" using a set of conditional expressions instead of a list of rules

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, logic, rule, conditional

Suppose that I have two linear functions

```
f[x_] := f0 + f1 x
g[x_] := g0 + g1 x
```

and a (possibly rather complicated) set of conditional expressions, obtained through Reduce.  For example, we might have something like this:

```
conditions = (f0 == f1 && g0 == 0) || (f0 == g1 && g0 == f1)
```

What I would like to do is write something like

```
{f[x],g[x]} /. conditions
```

and receive as output the set of pairs of $f$ and $g$ adhering to that formula.  In this case we'd have

```
{{a + ax, bx}, {a + bx, b + ax}}
```

(or maybe `{{f0 + f0x, g1x}, {f0 + f1x, f1 + f0x}}` to stick with original variable names).

How can I do this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I get the conditions through `Reduce`ing a system of equations in $g_0,g_1,f_0,f_1$ and then `FullSimplify`ing, so these should be solutions.  I'm really just trying to transform the coefficient logic into polynomial logic.

Comment: According to the documentation for [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html#73744098), this is how: `{f[x], g[x]} /. {ToRules@conditions}`.  The only issue is adjusting the variables in `Reduce` to get them in the order you desire. (It's unclear whether you want `f0` replaced by `f1` or vice versa, or sometimes both.)

Comment: As suggested by MichaelE2 `{f[x], g[x]} /. {ToRules @ conditions}` is what you need. See e.g. [How to get intersection values from a parametric graph?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph/33952#33952) where `Solve` couldn't provide solutions so we had used `ToRules @ Reduce[...]`. Another useful method  you might find here: [Simplifying expressions with square roots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29310/simplifying-expressions-with-square-roots/29357#29357).

Answer (score 4):

First convert your conditions to a list of [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html)s

```
myrules = Apply[List, conditions /. {Equal -> Rule}, {0, 1}]
```

which gives

[image]

Then [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) those [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html)s to your [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/List.html) using a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) and [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) ([`/@`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html))

```
ReplaceAll[{f[x], g[x]}, #] & /@ myrules
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Very nice result. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
Assuming[#, Simplify[{f[x], g[x]}]] & /@ List @@ conditions
```

> ```
> {{f1 (1 + x), g1 x}, {g1 + g0 x, g0 + g1 x}}
> ```

Which, technically but with switched constants, is what is desired.