# Simplification of algebraic expression

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I found an entry of a matrix from two different methods using mathematica. 
Which are given as;

```
g/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + g^2 - Sqrt[1 + g^2]])
```

and

```
1/Sqrt[2 + (2 - 2 Sqrt[1 + g^2])/g^2].
```

Logically these expression should be same, and they simplify to same result when i do it on paper. But when i plot these expressions for `{g,-5,5}`, it gives different plots on mathematica. What is happening?

Comment: `Sqrt[g^2]` is not equal to `g`, when `g` is negative.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, but these should reduce to single simplified form?

Comment: @Usman All you need you could find here: [Simplifying expressions with square roots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29310/simplifying-expressions-with-square-roots/29357#29357)

Comment: @Usman, No.  Sqrt[g^2] is a Mathematica function equal to `g` for `g > 0` and to `-g` for `g < 0`.  To go from your first expression to your second involves multiplying the first function by `Sqrt[g^2]/g`, which is not equal to one for negative g.

Comment: The two plots are exactly the same for `g>0` but not for `g<0`, as per bbgodfrey's comment.

Answer (score 2):

These are two simplifications of the same second expression with different ConplexityFunction used:

```
 Simplify[1/Sqrt[2 + (2 - 2 Sqrt[1 + g^2])/g^2], g > 0]

Simplify[1/Sqrt[2 + (2 - 2 Sqrt[1 + g^2])/g^2], g > 0, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (StringLength[ToString[#]] &)]
```

yielding the following:

```
(*  1/Sqrt[2 + (2 - 2 Sqrt[1 + g^2])/g^2]  *)
(*  g/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + g^2 - Sqrt[1 + g^2]])  *)
```

Have fun!