# FullSimplify weird behavior

Tags: simplifying-expressions

`FullSimplify` gives me two different results for similar expressions

```
exp1 = Sqrt[((a (b+m (c-2 d)^2)^2)/(m (c-2d)^2))];
exp2 = exp1 /. {b -> b1 + b2};
FullSimplify[exp1, {m > 0, a > 0, b > 0, c > 2 d, d > 0}]
FullSimplify[exp2, {m > 0, a > 0, b1 > 0, b2 > 0, c > 2 d, d > 0}]
```

Can someone explain why it is so?

Comment: Simplification can be finicky; it may stop at a "good enough" level. Consider also that what expression is to be considered simpler is sometimes in the eye of the beholder. In your case, it appears that you can nudge the second simplification in the direction you want by using `PowerExpand` on `exp2`, i.e. `FullSimplify[
 PowerExpand@exp2, yourConditions]`. You might also be interested in this discussion: [Advice for *Mathematica* as a mathematician's aid](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92686/27951) and [4522](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4522/27951).